C++11 using is_pointer to suitably dereference pointer
I write a compare function in C++ that should dereference only when T is of pointer type:
template<class T> bool compare(const T& left, const T& right)
 {
 if (is_pointer<T>::value)
   return *left <= *right;
 return left <= right;
 }

But it tries to dereference when T is int:
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)


if -> if constexpr.

ot: most of the time you want to compare something <= is the wrong way to implement the comparison.

Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()" and If statement at compile time

you can also use std::less or to stay with <= and a single call you can use !std::greater

The problem is that even though the if statement is never entered, the statement
return *left <= *right;

still has to be correct (syntactically and semantically).
An int does not have a unary * operator, so it's not valid semantically.
Similarly, it is not possible to write the following (similar to your case):
// invalid semantics in if statement
if (false) 0 = 0;
// invalid syntax in if statement
if (false) #@$#@ #@%#@ gjrwiuthui 4325@#$%@#$%;

C++17 Solution
One way to make it work is to use if constexpr (C++17), which treats the statement as a "discarded statement" if the condition is false.
This means that the compiler wouldn't attempt to apply * to the int at all; it would remove that part entirely:
if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
   return *left <= *right;

See also Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()"
C++11 Solution
You can have two different function templates; one which can only get called if the arguments are pointers.
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type
compare(const T& left, const T& right)
{
    return *left <= *right;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_pointer<T>::value, bool>::type
compare(const T& left, const T& right)
{
    return left <= right;
}

See also How Does std::enable_if work?
